# Why doesn't DefaultStyleKey change the default style for my subclasses?

Tags: c#, wpf, default

I have a base class called `Handle` from which I derive several base classes such as `RectHandle` and `EllipseHandle`.  In those subclasses I have attempted to override the default style key to point to `Handle` but a style targeting `Handle` is not applied. I still have to explicitly target `RectHandle` or `EllipseHandle` either directly, or via a 'BasedOn' style.  What am I missing?

Here's the MSDN excerpt for DefaultStyleKeyProperty:

> A control typically overrides the default value of this property to be its own type, but in some cases could also use a base type for which a style in the theme dictionaries exists.

Here's my code

```
public abstract class Handle : Shape
{
    static Handle()
    {
        WidthProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(Handle),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(10.0));

        HeightProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(Handle),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(10.0));

        FillProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(Handle),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Yellow));

        StrokeProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(Handle),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Gray));

        StrokeThicknessProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(Handle),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(2.0));
    }
}

public class RectHandle : Handle
{
    static RectHandle()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(RectHandle),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Handle)));
    }

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            var origin = new Point(-RenderSize.Width / 2, -RenderSize.Height / 2);
            var rect = new Rect(origin, RenderSize);
            return new RectangleGeometry(rect);
        }
    }
}

public class EllipseHandle : Handle
{
    static RectHandle()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(EllipseHandle),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Handle)));
    }

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            var origin = new Point(-RenderSize.Width / 2, -RenderSize.Height / 2);
            var rect = new Rect(origin, RenderSize);
            return new EllipseGeometry(rect);
        }
    }
}
```

And the style...

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type annotations:Handle}">
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

Again, this doesn't work.

My work-around is to create two other styles based on the first, but I thought that was the entire point of the `DefaultStyleKey` property.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type annotations:Handle}">
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type annotations:RectHandle}"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type annotations:Handle}}" />

<Style TargetType="{x:Type annotations:EllipseHandle}"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type annotations:Handle}}" />
```

Comment: Your work-around is right way

Comment: I see you deleted your original comment that points to my solution.  But that doesn't explain explicitly setting the DefaultStyleKeyProperty's metadata.  Your solution works if that's not the case, of course, but if you set it, 'BasedOn' shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.  The `DefaultStyleKey` property ***only refers to styles defined in a theme***, or in `Generic.xaml` under Themes.  If I move my `Handle` style there, all of a sudden, it works. If I instead copy it local to the window, which I had done, it doesn't.  Interesting that the lookups are different.